# Зафиксировать элемент при изменении окна браузера

Tags: html, css

Нужно, чтобы при изменении размера окна браузера, элемент оставался на той же точке фонового изображения. Пример на скрине обведен красным цветом. Заранее благодарю! [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Как-то давно писал похожее, суть в том, чтобы располагать эти "маркеры" именно через процентное соотношение, относительно изображения.
В таком случае при изменении размера изображения "маркеры" будут менять своё положение пропорционально.
Из минусов, если изображение должно меняться, тогда позицию "маркеров" тоже потребуется "пересчитать".

```css
.image-areas {
  display: inline-block;
  max-width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

.image-areas>img {
  display: block;
  width: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  margin: 0;
}

.image-areas-marker {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.075);
  background-image: radial-gradient(circle at center, #fff 5px, transparent 5.25px);
  -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(1px);
          backdrop-filter: blur(1px);
  position: absolute;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transition: transform .3s ease;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.image-areas-marker:hover {
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(1.25);
}
```

```html
<div class="image-areas">
  <img src="https://i.imgur.com/4wUu599.png" />
  <div class="image-areas-marker" style="left: 23%; top: 55%;"></div>
  <div class="image-areas-marker" style="left: 88%; top: 18%;"></div>
  <div class="image-areas-marker" style="left: 52.5%; top: 75%;"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Большое спасибо! calc + % помогли. Вроде работает)